# How to pass a variable name to dplyr's group_by()

Tags: r, variables, group-by, dplyr

I can calculate the rank of the values (`val`) in my dataframe `df` within the group `name1` with the code:

```
res  <- df %>% arrange(val) %>% group_by(name1) %>% mutate(RANK=row_number())
```

Instead of writing the column "name1" in the code, I want to pass it as variable, eg `crit = "name1"`. However, the code below does not work since `crit1` is assumed to be the column name instead of a variable name.

```
res  <- df %>% arrange(val) %>% group_by(crit1) %>% mutate(RANK=row_number())
```

How can I pass `crit1` in the code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 45):

We can use `group_by_`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    arrange(val) %>% 
    group_by_(.dots=crit1) %>%
    mutate(RANK=row_number()) 
#Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
#Groups: name1, name2 [7]

#            val name1 name2  RANK
#          <dbl> <chr> <chr> <int>
#1  -0.848370044     b     c     1
#2  -0.583627199     a     a     1
#3  -0.545880758     a     a     2
#4  -0.466495124     b     b     1
#5   0.002311942     a     c     1
#6   0.266021979     c     a     1
#7   0.419623149     c     b     1
#8   0.444585270     a     c     2
#9   0.536585304     b     a     1
1#0  0.847460017     a     c     3
```

#### Update

`group_by_` is deprecated in the recent versions (now using `dplyr` version - `0.8.1`), so we can use `group_by_at` which takes a vector of strings as input variables

```
df %>%
  arrange(val) %>% 
  group_by_at(crit1) %>%
  mutate(RANK=row_number())
```

---

Or another option is to convert to symbols (`syms` from `rlang`) and evaluate (`!!!`)

```
df %>%
   arrange(val) %>% 
   group_by(!!! rlang::syms(crit1)) %>% 
   mutate(RANK = row_number())
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(val = rnorm(10), name1= sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace=TRUE), 
         name2 = sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace=TRUE), 
 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

crit1 <- c("name1", "name2")
```

Comment: group_by_() is deprecated.

Comment: @Helen Thanks for notifying.  I added two options that work with the current version of `dplyr`

Comment: `dplyr` also has `syms` function, no need to specify `rlang` explicitly.

Answer (score 20):

### Update with dplyr 1.0.0

The new `across` syntax eliminates the need for `!!! rlang::syms()`. So you can now simplify the code by:

```
df %>%
   arrange(val) %>% 
   group_by(across(all_of(crit1))) %>% 
   mutate(RANK = row_number())
```

Comment: If you're grouping by any further columns it's: group_by(across(all_of(crit1)), additional_column_not_in_crit1) %>%

Comment: Is `all_of` needed here? I seem to be getting the same results with and without it.

Answer (score 4):

Facing a similar task I could successfully work with these two options.

**Use [`across()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html):**

```
for (crit in names(df)) {
  print(df |> 
          # all_of() is not needed here
          group_by(across(crit)) |> 
          count())
}
```

**Use [`syms()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/sym.html) and `!!`:**

```
crits = syms(names(df))

for (crit in crits) {
  print(df |> 
          # the use of !! instead of !!! is now encouraged 
          group_by(!!crit) |> 
          count())
}
```